# Inserting records into a heap takes a really long time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a pre-defined table of about 35 fields, mostly defined as nvarchar(255) and nullable.

There are no constraints, indexes or triggers of any kind on this table.

I have a query that returns roughly 32k records. If I insert this directly into a new permanent table on the fly, ie

```
SELECT <<fields>> INTO dbo.MadeUpTable01 FROM <<my query goes here>>
```

it takes about 3 seconds.

When I try to insert into my real, pre-defined table, either directly from my query or from my new permanent table, like this:

```
INSERT dbo.MyRealTable SELECT * FROM dbo.MadeUpTable01
```

then it takes upwards of 25 seconds.

I'm the only person working on this server, and the DBA has confirmed there is no issue with I/O, CPU, temp table, etc. I'm stumped. What is the problem?

EDIT: you can see here that the table insert is 65% of the query cost, though there should be nothing on this table to inhibit an insert.

[image: execution plan]

Comment: Well the obvious things to check would be a) does your permanent table have any insert triggers on it, and b) does that table have any indices on it?  If yes to these questions, it could substantially slow down an insert versus an otherwise bare table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference in time is caused by `logging`.

In case of

> SELECT <> INTO dbo.MadeUpTable01 FROM <>

you have `minimal logging` in `simple` and `bulk logged` recovery models.
I guess your db is in `simple` because if no your `select into` took nearly same time that `insert into`.

> INSERT dbo.MyRealTable SELECT * FROM dbo.MadeUpTable01

is `fully logged` in your case because you did not use `tablock` hint on the destination table.

Here [The Data Loading Performance Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd425070(v=sql.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) you can find more information on `logging` and `minimal logging` conditions.

Comment: Interesting. That's a bummer, because I can't block the table on inserts, but with those hints, it is reliably faster. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: In two words: when you make SELECT INTO, you are the only who accesses this table, server knows this and puts in log only allocated page numbers, in case you make a rollback that's enough to know these pages to unallocate them. When you insert with tablock, it's the same situation, only page numbers vcan be logged. But when others can insert there can be new rows in between your rows so all the inserts are logged row per row

Comment: Thats really interesting!